# osm2pgsql. Loading data into tables with non-standard columns

Tags: postgis, osm2pgsql

I have an * .osm file with a lot of data. To load the data into postgis I use osm2pgsql.
Tell me, please, how to load in the table "my_table" data that have amenity = parking. Coordinates of polygons must be written in the "polygon" field